# EJS Error Failed to lookup view (ejs is not getting the path?)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im getting this error that I can't solve, I tried different ways and I still getting the same error,

I tried with;

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '../src/views'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../src/views'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src' , 'views'));
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "requests_page" in views directory "/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/views"
    at Function.render (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at noc_request_controller.render_requests_page (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/src/controllers/noc_requests.controllers.js:17:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/fcarreon/Desktop/Dev/noc_ops_v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Here my code and my project structure.

server.js

```
// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '../src/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

structure

```
.
├── config
│   ├── app.js
│   └── server.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── scripts
│   └── db.js
└── src
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── index.controllers.js
    │   └── noc_requests.controllers.js
    ├── middlewares
    ├── models
    │   └── noc_request_model.js
    ├── routes
    │   ├── index.routes.js
    │   └── noc_requests.routes.js
    └── views
        ├── partials
        └── requests_page.ejs

9 directories, 11 files
```

noc_requests.controllers.js(controller function);

```
noc_request_controller.render_requests_page = (req, res) => {
    res.render("requests_page")
}
```

Comment: why dont you console.log `path.join(__dirname + '../src/views')` and see whether it gives you right directory path